# Not able to import a pom dependencies into another

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, pom.xml

I have created a pom file with some common dependencies that I would like to use for my projects. The pom has a packaging of type pom. I have pushed it to my nexus repository: https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/snapshots/content/com/gwidgets/gwt-spring-boot-starter/1.0-SNAPSHOT/gwt-spring-boot-starter-1.0-20170526.141419-3.pom, and now I am trying to import it into other projects, but the dependencies are not resolved by maven. Here is the full pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>


    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project</description>

        <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gwidgets</groupId>
            <artifactId>gwt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>com.gwidgets</groupId>
         <artifactId>gwt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
         <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
          <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency> 
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

        <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>war</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>war</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

I have tried adding a `dependencyManagement` section, without any luck. Am I missing something? Is this not allowed by maven? Any help would be great. Here are the error that I am getting when trying to do the GWT compilation:

```
package com.google.gwt.core.client does not exist
cannot find symbol: class EntryPoint
```

which simply means that the dependencies are not there.

Comment: Sorry! some guy was trying to close it because he says that this has nothing to do maven, it is a pure maven issue. he thinks he is smarter than everybody here. I took note of your answer. If it works, than you can repost it, and I will mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: The import scope only works in ´dependencyManagement`.

Comment: All I want to achieve is having a bunch of dependencies and gathering them into a pom, and then import that pom into several projects which will import its dependencies transitively, is this achievable using Maven?

Comment: It is possible with a super pom, where you define dependencyManagement on the parent and the children define dependencies.  You can also define dependencies on the super pom which will inherit to each children, but that this is not typical. You should define dependencies for each child module.

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Super_POM

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: after doing some research, it does not seem to be possible to import a pom and have its dependencies resolved transitively with Maven unless using a parent pom. In my current settings, the projects already have a parent pom, so the only solution is to copy paste all the dependencies into the target pom. It would nice to have this feature in Maven in the future.